# Punctuation in bibliography with multiple languages

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, punctuation, languages, babel

In a document written in a given language (in my case French but it may not matter so much) I have a bibliography mixing entries in different languages (in this case French, English and German). I would like to get the punctuation (basically quotation marks and spacing before double punctuation or question marks) right for each entry.

In this simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british,french]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A2012,
author = {Author, A},
title = {A ``paper'': written in english?},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {70--76},
}
@article{B2012,
author = {Auteur, B},
title = {Un \og article\fg : \'ecrit en fran\c{c}ais ?},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {77--79},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{A2012}, \cite{B2012}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I obtain

[image]

`babel` has added spacing before the colon and question mark for the english entry. One way to avoid that is to add `\NoAutoSpaceBeforeFDP` in the preamble. But then the space before the colon is eaten up by `babel` also in the french entry. I can make sure this does not happen by putting manually an unbreakable space in
the bibliographic entry. However, this seems like an inconvenient hack to me.

Is there a systematic way to make sure that the spacing is correct in each entry? (and if possible, to obtain the correct quotation marks without entering them manually as I have done in the example?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is yet another reason to switch to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (here: in combination with [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)). (And with [`biblatex-trad`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-trad) there's even a `trad-plain` style!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british,french]{babel}
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=trad-plain,babel=other]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A2012,
hyphenation = {british},
author = {Author, A},
title = {A \enquote{paper}: written in english?},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {70--76},
}
@article{B2012,
hyphenation = {french},
author = {Auteur, B},
title = {Un \enquote{article}: \'ecrit en fran\c{c}ais?},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {77--79},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{A2012}, \cite{B2012}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, I would go for that if it were not for the custom `.bst` I'm using in this case...

Answer (score 14):

use

```
title = {\foreignlanguage{british}{A ``paper'': written in english?}},
```

[image]

is only a problem if you have an author-title style.

Comment: With `\otherlanguage` *all* following entries in the bibliography will inherit the `british` language. So it's wrong; the correct command to use is `\foreignlanguage`

Comment: sigh ... I suppose I will mismatch these two macros for at least the next ten years ...

Comment: It's easy: `otherlanguage` is an environment!

Answer (score 5):

A possible strategy is to use `babelbib`. However the standard `babplain` style has a glitch regarding colons, which however also shows with `plain` in your example: the colon following the volume number is spaced and it shouldn't be.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british,french]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\renewcommand{\btxauthorcolon}{,}
\providecommand{\btxvolumecolon}{\string:}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A2012,
author = {Author, A},
title = {A ``paper'': written in english?},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {70--76},
language={british},
}
@article{B2012,
author = {Auteur, B},
title = {Un \og article\fg: \'ecrit en fran\c{c}ais ?},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {77--79},
language={french},
}
@article{C2012,
author = {Zuteur, B},
title = {Un \og article\fg: \'ecrit en fran\c{c}ais ?},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {77--79},
language={french},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{A2012}, \cite{B2012}, \cite{C2012}

\bibliographystyle{mybabplain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The file `mybabplain.bst` is just the same as `babplain.bst`, with a single change: the function `format.vol.num.pages` (lines 631–650) should be changed to

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { "\btxvolumecolon {}" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

The change is just `\btxvolumecolon {}` to replace `:`. In the document preamble I've provided a default definition for `\btxvolumecolon`.

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting solution, however, it only works with the `babelbib` bibliography styles if I understood correctly. In this precise case, I have a custom `.bst` (in which I have no volume colon by the way) although I chose `plain.bst` for the example. I'll have a look to see if it is difficult to merge my custom `.bst` with a `babelbib` style.

Comment: @Corentin I believe that `makebst` can output `babelbib` compatible `.bst` files.