# How to get language dependent quotation marks in citations with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, languages

I cite german and french articles. In my bibliography the titles are given in quotation marks. Now, I would like to have the quotation marks dependent on the language of the article.
I thought `biblatex` together with `csquotes` would handle this automatically but in fact all titles have german quotation marks (as this is the language of the main text). This is my header:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english,american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,babel=other]{biblatex}
```

Comment: My inclination would be to advise against using different types of quotation marks for pieces published in German and French. Why? Well, why adjust only the style of the quotation marks? After all, German and French typographic conventions for referencing entries differ considerably along many aspects, including the use of small-cap or regular letters for authors' names and the spacing around certain punctuation marks (such as colons and semicolons). I'd say, either go whole-hog and adjust *all* typographic aspects, or stick with one set of typographic conventions.

Comment: Please provide a *complete* [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). In your case a `bib` file would also be needed.

Comment: I had the same problem recently and asked here: you should find satisfactory answers here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/punctuation-in-bibliography-with-multiple-languages. Withe `trad-plain` style it is automatic.