# Punctuations rules in multilingual bilbiography

Tags: biblatex, babel

I would like a (biblatex) bibliography where:

- The language of the bibliography is always the same, regardless of the language of the entry. I do not want translation or localization of things like: page or volume number, translator or editor data, author's name layout...
- The title of the entries follow the punctuation spacing rules of the language of the entry. Typically: no space before ? in english, unbreakable space before ? in french.

I've tested various combinations of `language` and `autolang` parameters for biblatex, whitout success so far.
For example in the MWE below:

- `autolang=other`

  - correct punctuation spacing to switch punctuation rules, following the `langid` of each entry.
  - unwanted localization like: "Trans. by"/"Trad. par", "p."/"pp.", small capital or not for the name of the author...
- `autolang=hyphen`

  - correct single language for the bibliography ("Trad. par" in both cases)
  - incorrect typography: the space before ? is missing in french.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{compagnon,
  author     = {Compagnon, Antoine},
  translator = {Même, Moi},
  date       = {1998},
  title      = {Titre: aléatoire?},
  pages      = {306-723},
  langid     = {french},
}
@book{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title        = {Random: title?},
  translator   = {Self, My},
  date         = {1961},
  pages        = {579-588},
  langid       = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=verbose-trad2,
    singletitle=true,
    autolang=other,
]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcite{compagnon}
\footcite{glashow}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Potential close questions:

- Adding `\foreignlanguage{...}` in the title field is often suggested. I can't find again a very didactic post from user moewe explaining that biblatex does not have a per-field language options and presenting distinct strategies.
- Correct [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/punctuation-in-bibliography-with-multiple-languages), but with unwanted localisation at the entry level.
- Correct [hyphenation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260954/change-language-on-a-per-field-basis), but not the punctuation rules.
- Potential [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479489) in lualatex? Not sure to understand why it should be different.

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/757 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444016/35864 might be interesting.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the hints. Can't figure out how get what I need yet... Am I missing something obvious or is it genuinely tricky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/757 and [Change language on a per field basis, part 2: Fonts, case transformation and sorting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444016/35864) this is pretty tricky and would ideally be addressed in the `biblatex` core. But that needs a lot of groundwork that still is being worked on.

Here is a `babel` version of the `polyglossia`-based answer to [Change language on a per field basis, part 2: Fonts, case transformation and sorting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444016/35864) that should get you a little further.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=verbose-trad2,
    singletitle=true,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@thefakelangenv{otherlanguage}%

\def\blx@beglang@fake{%
  \blx@clearlang
  \begingroup
  \ifdef\abx@field@langid
    {\def\blx@endlang@fake{%
       \end{otherlanguage*}%
       \endgroup}%
     \begin{otherlanguage*}{\abx@field@langid}}
    {}}

\let\blx@endlang@fake\relax

\renewrobustcmd*{\blx@imc@printfield}[2][]{%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{#2}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{ffd}{#1}{#2}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@begunit
        \let\blx@theformat@outer\blx@theformat
        \def\blx@theformat##1{\blx@theformat@outer{\blx@beglang@fake ##1\blx@endlang@fake}}%
        \edef\currentfield{#2}%
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\blx@theformat
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter{\csname abx@field@#2\endcsname}%
        \blx@endunit}}}

\long\def\blx@nameparser@i#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \ifblank{#1}
    {}
    {\setkeys{blx@opt@name}{#1}}%
  \setkeys{blx@opt@namepart}{#2}%
  \blx@beglang@fake\blx@theformat{#2}\blx@endlang@fake
  \endgroup}

\long\def\blx@listparser#1{%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {\blx@listbreak}
    {\ifnum\c@listcount<\c@liststart
     \else
       \blx@beglang@fake\blx@theformat{#1}\blx@endlang@fake
     \fi
     \advance\c@listcount\@ne
     \ifnum\c@listcount>\c@liststop
       \expandafter\blx@listbreak
     \fi
     \blx@listparser}}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{compagnon,
  author     = {Compagnon, Antoine and Someone Else},
  translator = {Même, Moi},
  date       = {1998},
  title      = {Titre: aléatoire?},
  pages      = {306-723},
  langid     = {french},
}
@book{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon and Someone Else},
  title        = {Random: title?},
  translator   = {Self, My},
  date         = {1961},
  pages        = {579-588},
  langid       = {english},
}
\end{filecontents} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcite{compagnon}
\footcite{glashow}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Compagnon, Antoine et Someone Else. Titre : aléatoire ? Trad. par Moi Même. 1998, 306-723." (with space before colon and question mark) "Glashow, Sheldon et Someone Else. Random: title? Trad. par My Self. 1961, 579-588." (without space before colon and question mark)]

---

As discussed in the comments, this approach has some shortcomings, because it is not always desirable to have the language switching code applied to the field contents directly.

I cannot offer a good alternative approach, since changing the language after field formats etc. have been applied effects bibstrings (which are supposed to stay the same). What I can offer is an ad-hoc solution that allows you to exempt certain fields from the language switching (you can of course reverse the logic to have language switching only for certain fields if that works better for you).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=verbose-trad2,
    singletitle=true,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mblx@exemptfields}{}
\newrobustcmd*{\ExemptFromLanguageSwitching}{%
  \forcsvlist{\listgadd\mblx@exemptfields}}

\def\blx@thefakelangenv{otherlanguage}%

\def\blx@beglang@fake{%
  \blx@clearlang
  \begingroup
  \ifdef\abx@field@langid
    {\def\blx@endlang@fake{%
       \end{otherlanguage*}%
       \endgroup}%
     \begin{otherlanguage*}{\abx@field@langid}}
    {}}

\let\blx@endlang@fake\relax

\renewrobustcmd*{\blx@imc@printfield}[2][]{%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{#2}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{ffd}{#1}{#2}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@begunit
        \ifinlist{#2}{\mblx@exemptfields}
          {}
          {\let\blx@theformat@outer\blx@theformat
           \def\blx@theformat##1{\blx@theformat@outer{\blx@beglang@fake ##1\blx@endlang@fake}}}%
        \edef\currentfield{#2}%
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\blx@theformat
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter{\csname abx@field@#2\endcsname}%
        \blx@endunit}}}


\catcode`\&=3
\def\blx@printnames#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@ifnameundef{#4}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\def\mblx@currentname{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@thewrapperformat{nwd}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@thewrapperformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{nfd}{#1}{#4}%
        \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
          {\blx@nounit}
          {\blx@begunit
           \blx@namesetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
           \blx@thewrapperformat{\expandafter\blx@nameparser\blx@thedata{}&}%
           \blx@endunit}}}}

\def\blx@indexnames#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@ifnameundef{#4}
    {}
    {\def\mblx@currentname{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@theformat{nid}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {}
       {\begingroup
        \blx@namesetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
        \blx@indexnamesetup
        \expandafter\blx@nameparser\blx@thedata{}&%
        \endgroup}}}

\long\def\blx@nameparser@i#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \ifblank{#1}
    {}
    {\setkeys{blx@opt@name}{#1}}%
  \setkeys{blx@opt@namepart}{#2}%
  \expandafter\ifinlist\expandafter{\mblx@currentname}{\mblx@exemptfields}
    {\blx@theformat{#2}}
    {\blx@beglang@fake\blx@theformat{#2}\blx@endlang@fake}%
  \endgroup}


\def\blx@printlist#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@iflistundef{#4}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\def\mblx@currentlist{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@thewrapperformat{lwd}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@thewrapperformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{lfd}{#1}{#4}%
        \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
          {\blx@nounit}
          {\blx@begunit
           \blx@listsetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
           \blx@thewrapperformat{\expandafter\blx@listparser\blx@thedata{}&}%
           \blx@endunit}}}}

\def\blx@indexlist#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@iflistundef{#4}
    {}
    {\def\mblx@currentlist{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@theformat{lid}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {}
       {\begingroup
        \blx@listsetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
        \expandafter\blx@listparser\blx@thedata{}&%
        \endgroup}}}

\long\def\blx@listparser#1{%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {\blx@listbreak}
    {\ifnum\c@listcount<\c@liststart
     \else
       \expandafter\ifinlist\expandafter{\mblx@currentlist}{\mblx@exemptfields}
         {\blx@theformat{#1}}
         {\blx@beglang@fake\blx@theformat{#1}\blx@endlang@fake}%
     \fi
     \advance\c@listcount\@ne
     \ifnum\c@listcount>\c@liststop
       \expandafter\blx@listbreak
     \fi
     \blx@listparser}}
\makeatother
\catcode`\&=4

\ExemptFromLanguageSwitching{url,doi,eprint,pages}


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{compagnon,
  author     = {Compagnon, Antoine and Someone Else},
  translator = {Même, Moi},
  date       = {1998},
  title      = {Titre: aléatoire?},
  pages      = {306-723},
  langid     = {french},
  url        = {https://example.com/~stuff/more.pdf},
}
@book{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon and Someone Else},
  title        = {Random: title?},
  translator   = {Self, My},
  date         = {1961},
  pages        = {579-588},
  langid       = {english},
  url          = {https://example.com/~stuff/more.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcite{compagnon}
\footcite{glashow}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some feedbacks:
1. With an url field, I get the following output ```url : \blx@beglang@fakeugly%20test-url\blx@endlang@fake.``` 
2. The little "p." indicating (in french) a page, pages range or total page number disappears.
Is this easily solvable or would the hack become too complex? Thanks again anyhow!

Comment: @letax We can exempt fields from language switching (see the edit). But this shows that a general solution in the `biblatex` core is going to be extremely tricky.

Comment: Wow, I wish I could upvote again! It's always a bit scary as I don't understand the syntax/logic of the code, but so far it seems to work! Now, let's see how the 684 references of the full document behave...

Comment: For future readers: the patch was robust enough for my large document. Just make sure that every bib entry has a langid defined.

Comment: I stumble on **only one** incompatibility with your patch (great!): I make an automatic index using (yet) [another answer of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546554) I get a compilation error ```! Undefined control sequence. \blx@nameparser@i ...pandafter {\mblx@currentname```. I tried to exempt the ```author``` field in ```\ExemptFromLanguageSwitching``` without success. Should I post a new question or is this too complex too be handled with a patch?

Comment: @letax I'd need an example document to investigate. Either ask a new question or upload an example document to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/, https://gist.github.com/, ...

Comment: Sure! I'll post a new question in a few minutes.

Comment: New question posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/636483) thanks for the patient technical assistance!